# Few criterias in filtering - SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have problem. I want to filter my datas. My criterias: Date (between two dates), Dangerous (yes or not) and Place_of_problem. When I delete cirterion about date - it works but when I add date - shows nothing. Date1, Date2, Dangerous and Place_of_problem are combobox from Form1.

```
SELECT Accident.ID_Accident, Accident.Date, Accident.Dangerous, Accident.Place_of_problem,
FROM Accident
WHERE (((Accident.Dangerous) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Dangerous] & "*") AND ((Accident.Place_of_problem) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Place_of_problem] & "*") AND (Accident.Date) Between [Forms]![Form1]![Date1] And [Forms]![Form1]![Date2]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying these as parameters:

```sql
PARAMETERS [Forms]![Form1]![Date1] DateTime, [Forms]![Form1]![Date2] DateTime;
SELECT Accident.ID_Accident, Accident.Date, Accident.Dangerous, Accident.Place_of_problem,
FROM Accident
WHERE (((Accident.Dangerous) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Dangerous] & "*") AND ((Accident.Place_of_problem) Like "*" & [Forms]![Form1]![Place_of_problem] & "*") AND (Accident.Date) Between [Forms]![Form1]![Date1] And [Forms]![Form1]![Date2]));
```